# append response from $http() to div

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new to Angularjs and I just can't figure out how to append a reply from $http() to a div(or any other element for that matter).

I've been using jQuery for a while and I know how to do it using that library, which is why I'm finding it hard to use Angular for this task.

I have a directive that uses $http.get() to get data from a PHP proxy. I'm trying to append the response from that $http() request to a div.

This is what I got right now:

```
app.directive('displayArticle', ['$http', '$log', function ($http, $log) {
    var replyFromProxy = angular.element('<div></div>');

    $http.get('gp-proxy.php').
        success(function (data) {
            // $log.info(data);

            replyFromProxy = angular.element('<div>' + data + '</div>');
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // $log.error(data);
            // $log.error(status);
            // $log.error(headers);
            // $log.error(config);
        });

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/displayArticle.html',
        compile: function (tElem) {
            tElem.append(replyFromProxy);
        }
    };
}]);
```

`displayArticle.html` contains an empty div

What am I doing wrong?
Is there an easier or better way to do this?

Edit: What I'm trying to do is use `gp-proxy.php` to load an external page into my own webpage. The host doesn't allow CORS so this was my back-up plan.

Using `ng-include` in my template feels too static and not dynamic enough since I'd like to be able to load in different pages depending on what I click on in the original page.

Comment: $log.info(data) returns the data?

Comment: @TiagoBarreto yes it does. it works perfectly fine.
I just don't know how to append the response into the webpage.

Comment: The $http.get and compile functions are not synchronous. When your compile function is executed, 'replyFromProxy' hasn't completed yet.  You should put gp-proxy.php inside your template using ng-include.

Comment: @pixelbits I managed to append the response using ng-include, but that doesn't feel like the way to go. It feels too static.  See edit to OP for more details.

Comment: It all depends on what you're trying to do. Based on what you've described, ng-include should be more angular and less jquery

Comment: @rymdsylt: `ngInclude` ιs not at all static. It can be bound to a variable in your $scope (to any Angular expression actually) and it will update the view whenever its source attribute (i.e. the value of the expression) changes. It feels static because (with your jQuery background) you can't believe how much work can Angular save you :D